# Calling Awk in a shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I have this command which executes correctly if run directly on the terminal.

```
awk '/word/ {print NR}' file.txt | head -n 1
```

The purpose is to find the line number of the line on which the word `'word'` first appears in `file.txt`.

But when I put it in a script file, it doens't seem to work.

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
        echo "Usage: $0 <word> <filename>"
        exit 1
fi

awk '/$1/ {print NR}' $2 | head -n 1
```

So what did I do wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace the single quotes with double quotes so that the `$1` is evaluated by the shell:

```
awk "/$1/ {print NR}" $2 | head -n 1
```

Comment: This will break if `word` contains a slash.

Comment: It will also break if `word` contains a single quote. There are various things you can do in the shell to work around that though.

Answer (score 6):

In the shell, single-quotes prevent parameter-substitution; so if your script is invoked like this:

```
script.sh word
```

then you *want* to run this AWK program:

```
/word/ {print NR}
```

but you're *actually* running this one:

```
/$1/ {print NR}
```

and needless to say, AWK has no idea what `$1` is supposed to be.

To fix this, change your single-quotes to double-quotes:

```
awk "/$1/ {print NR}" $2 | head -n 1
```

so that the shell will substitute `word` for `$1`.

Answer (score 6):

You should use AWK's variable passing feature:

```
awk -v patt="$1" '$0 ~ patt {print NR; exit}' "$2"
```

The `exit` makes the `head -1` unnecessary.

Comment: @user1508893: Because you can't put an AWK variable (e.g. `patt`) inside `//`.

Answer (score 2):

you could also pass the value as a variable to awk:

```
awk -v varA=$1 '{if(match($0,varA)>0){print NR;}}' $2 | head -n 1
```

Seems more cumbersome than the above, but illustrates passing vars.

Comment: I dont understand why you need `$0` here. `$0` is the name of my script, right? How cone it's needed?

Comment: @user1508893: In AWK, `$0` means the whole current line of input data.